# Passende Übersetzung von „I am hurting“

Tags: english-to-german, phrase

Ich suche nach einem Ausdruck, der den englischen Ausdruck [**I am hurting**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48415/i-am-hurting-in-the-meaning-of-i-am-hurt-why) widerspiegelt. Es geht um emotionalen Schmerz, ohne näher zu definieren, wodurch oder durch wen er verursacht wurde.

Bis jetzt sind mir nur folgende Ausdrücke eingefallen, mit denen ich nicht zufrieden bin

- Es schmerzt mich. *(Der Ausdruck schreit nach der Frage „Was schmerzt denn?“)*
- In mir schmerzt es. *(Den Ausdruck finde ich ein bisschen melodramatisch)*
- Ich habe Schmerzen. *(Impliziert eher körperliche Schmerzen)*
- Es tut mir weh. *(wie erster Vorschlag: „Was tut denn weh?“)*

Es kann natürlich auch sein, dass es dafür keine adäquate Übersetzung gibt, dann muss ich mir eine Umschreibung einfallen lassen – auch dafür bin ich offen.

---

**Edit**

Ich möchte einen Grund oder Kontext angeben.

Stellt es euch als Antwort auf die Frage „Wie geht es dir?“ vor.

Antworten könnten lauten:

- Es geht mir gut.
- Es geht mir schlecht.
- Ich bin fröhlich.
- Ich bin hungrig
- Ich bin müde.
- I am hurting.

Gerade ist mir noch das Verb **leiden** eingefallen. Wobei auch leiden vielleicht auch sehr dramatisch klingt?

Comment: Es tut mir in der Seele weh.

Comment: Aber grundsätzlich gibt ja der Kontext an, worum es geht. "Es tut mir weh", "Es schmerzt mich" und "Mir schmerzt es" sind durchaus aussagekräftig genug. Gegebenenfalls gefolgt von einem "dass [Ursache]", spätestens dann ist klar, was gemeint ist.

Comment: danke für die Antworten, siehe mein Edit.

Comment: Hier zur Bedeutung von "I am hurting" http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48415/i-am-hurting-in-the-meaning-of-i-am-hurt-why (ich musste, das nämlich erst googlen um die Frage zu verstehen)

Comment: @Iris danke für die Referenz, hab sie eingebaut

Comment: Ich finde "Es geht mir schlecht" trifft "I am hurting" eigentlich ganz gut, da "jdm. schlecht sein" auch häufig den emotionalen Zustand meint.

Comment: @Iris Oxford und Merriam-Webster definieren diese Bedeutung auch: to feel unhappy or upset

Comment: @jera Dein Edit dreht die Frage in eine andere Richtung. Aber die Antwort "I'm hurting" auf die Frage "How are you" finde ich ungewöhnlich. Insbesondere im Englischen. Einzig wenn ich einen sehr guten Freund explizit frage, wie es ihm ergeht (weil ich weiß, dass er eine schwere Zeit durchmacht), würde ich diese Antwort erwarten. Dann ist meine Frage aber auch eher "Wie fühlst du dich?" bzw. das "Wie geht es dir" ist mit sehr softer, mitfühlsamer Stimme gesprochen. In jedem Fall wird die Antwort darauf keine wörtl. Übersetzung zu "hurt" sein. "Leiden" ist schon gut, ggf aber wirklich zu stark.

Comment: Natürlich wäre das eine komische Antwort auf die Frage "Wie geht es dir?" Ich möchte damit sagen, dass ich den Satz ohne Kontext stehen lassen möchte und trotzdem soll klar sein, dass ich emotionalen Schmerz empfinde.

Comment: @jera Ohne Kontext sind "Mir schmerzt es", "Es schmerzt mich" und "Es tut mir weh" wohl die besten Übersetzungen. Aber der Kontext ändert eben alles. Du kannst ein und denselben Satz in unterschiedlichen Situation unterschiedlich übersetzen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je nach Tiefe des Schmerzes (und ob es sich um körperlichen oder seelischen Schmerz handelt) fallen mir folgende Ausdrücke ein:

1. Ich bin bekümmert
2. Ich bin bedrückt
3. Ich mache grade eine schlechte Zeit durch
4. Etwas belastet mich
5. Etwas liegt mir auf der Seele
6. Ich bin gekränkt
7. Ich bin verletzt/Das hat mich verletzt
8. Ich bin wirklich geschlagen
9. Etwas quält mich
10. Ich fühle mich elend
11. Ich leide

Comment: +1 Ich leide. Ich leide mit Dir und darbe. Der Rest ist größtenteils überspezifisch und daher eine  schlechte Übersetzung.

Comment: Ja, mich spricht *Ich leide* als übersetzung auch sehr an, wenn ich darüber nachdenke. *Ich bin bekümmert* finde ich auch passend. Und obwohl *Ich bin verletzt* auf den ersten Blick auch nach körperlichem Leid aussieht, ist es wohl mit der richtigen Tonlage, Mimik und Gestik auch überaus passend!

Answer (score 1):

Die beste Entsprechung, die mir einfällt:

> Ich bin bekümmert.

Laut DWDS nimmt die Häufigkeit diese Wortes allerdings kontinuierlich ab

Answer (score 1):

Ich würde

> Ich bin niedergeschlagen/deprimiert

oder kurz:

> Ich bin depri

sagen.

> Es geht mir nicht gut.

oder

> Es geht mir schlecht.

würden meiner Meinung nach aber auch passen.

Alle diese Aussagen können alleine so stehen und beschreiben psychisches Leiden.